# Send form information to email using php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, send

I want to ask you for a help. I'm using simple time slot booking calendar, everything is working fine (details are transfered correctly in to msql database), but i can't send all form details to my email and also customer e-mail for a confirmation purpose.

I can only send ex. address info or name info but can't send both and also i can't send all details. Can you please help me. Thank you so much for any help from any of you guys!

book_slots.php:

```
<?php

include('php/connect.php');
include('new.php');  

if(isset($_POST['slots_booked'])) $slots_booked = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['slots_booked']);
if(isset($_POST['name'])) $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
if(isset($_POST['address'])) $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['address']);
if(isset($_POST['email'])) $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
if(isset($_POST['phone'])) $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['phone']);
if(isset($_POST['booking_date'])) $booking_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['booking_date']);
if(isset($_POST['cost_per_slot'])) $cost_per_slot = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cost_per_slot']);


$booking_array = array(
    "slots_booked" => $slots_booked,    
    "booking_date" => $booking_date,
    "cost_per_slot" => number_format($cost_per_slot, 2),
    "name" => $name,
    "address" => $address,
    "email" => $email,
    "phone" => $phone
);

$explode = explode('|', $slots_booked);

foreach($explode as $slot) {

    if(strlen($slot) > 0) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO bookings (date, start, name, address, email, phone) VALUES ('$booking_date', '$slot', '$name', '$address', '$email', '$phone')"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link)); 

    } // Close if

} // Close foreach

header( 'Location: thankyou.php' );


?>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php

// Make a MySQL Connection
$host="my host";
$user="db_xxx";
$password="mypasswoe";
$db = "db_xxx";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);
mysqli_select_db($link, $db) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

new.php:

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "booking@mydomain.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = "Booking Confirmation";
  $comment = "Hi, \n\n Thank you for joining  \n\n
Regards Site Admin \n\n";

  //send email
  mail($email, "$subject", "$comment", "From:" . $admin_email);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>

 <form method="post">
  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
  Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
  Message:Your Reservation has been made. Please check reservation detail below:<br />
  <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
  <textarea name="name" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: `or die(mysql_error()` that needs to be `or die(mysqli_error($link)` - You can't mix MySQL APIs. Plus, remove the quotes in `"$subject", "$comment"`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Thanks for reply i've make changes as you told me and also i've added error reporting, but it don't show anything just standard Thank you message

Comment: Just in case i receive e-mail from my form. Is it possible to receive all details which are in this form through email? Now i can only get information about one field information. Ex. if i change

`$comment = "Hi, \n\n Thank you for joining  \n\n
Regards Site Admin \n\n";`

to:

`$comment = $_REQUEST['address'];`

I will get e-mail with customer address information. But i need to receive all details like : name, phone, address, booking_time.

Is it possible. Thank you for any of your reply

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST) ){

//form validation vars
$formok = true;
$errors = array();

//sumbission data
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$time = date('H:i:s');

//form data
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//validate form data

//validate name is not empty
if(empty($name)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
}

//validate email address is not empty
if(empty($email)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";
//validate email address is valid
}elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
}

//validate message is not empty
if(empty($message)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a message";
}
//validate message is greater than 20 charcters
elseif(strlen($message) < 20){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Your message must be greater than 20 characters";
}
//send email if all is ok
if($formok){
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$email."(".$enquiry.")\r\n";   
    $emailbody = "<p>You have recieved a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p>";
    $emailbody .="<p><strong>Name: </strong>".$name."</p>";
    $emailbody .= "<p><strong>Email Address:</strong>".$email."</p>";
    $emailbody .= "<p><strong>Telephone:</strong>".$telephone."</p>";
    $emailbody .= "<p><strong>Enquiry:</strong>".$enquiry."</p>";
    $emailbody .="<p><strong>Message:</strong>".$message."</p>";
    $emailbody .= "This message was sent from the IP Address:".$ipaddress." on ".$date." at ".$time."</p>";
    mail("service@globalsx.com","New Enquiry",$emailbody,$headers); 
}
//what we need to return back to our form
$returndata = array(
    'posted_form_data' => array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'telephone' => $telephone,
        'enquiry' => $enquiry,
        'message' => $message
    ),
    'form_ok' => $formok,
    'errors' => $errors
);
//if this is not an ajax request
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
    //set session variables
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

    //redirect back to form
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
}
```

Comment: It's still not working, but thank you for your reply and help. Now i can't receive e-mail